# how to check accessibility for word add-in? what are the guidelines?

Tags: accessibility, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I am developing an add-in for word, how do I test and implement accessibility in that add-in?

what are the guidelines or standards for accessibility guidelines for add-in development? Is it the WCAG 2.x or UAAG 2.0? there is no clear documentation available by Microsoft on this subject.

appreciate any help.

Comment: This may be the documentation you are looking for:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/accessibility-guidelines

Comment: thank you @Jinghui-MSFT, its helpful although MS doesnt specify the standards (WCAG) anywhere.